# Difference between omp for and omp parallel

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have this code :

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,j = 0 ;
    int tid;
    # pragma omp parallel private(i,j,tid)
    {
       tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       printf("Thread %d\n",tid);
       for(i=0;i<10;i++){
          # pragma omp for
          for(j=0; j<10;j++){
             tid = omp_get_thread_num();
             printf("(i,j) = (%d,%d) Thread %d\n",i,j,tid);
          }
       }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Why the first "printf" is executed by each thread but not the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"omp parallel" starts a [parallel region](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#ParallelRegion).  When a thread enters that region, normally a team of threads is launched, with the thread entering becoming the master thread.  All the threads in the team then execute the code until the end of the parallel region, where the threads join back up to the master thread.

Because omp parallel starts a parallel region, this is where clauses like your `private(i,j,tid)` go clauses that define how variables are to be treated within the region (default, private, shared, reduction, etc) are given at the time the parallel region starts, along with clauses that optionally set the number of threads (num_threads).

But often having a number of threads execute exactly the same steps in a parallel region isn't what you want; you want each thread to execute a different task, or work on a separate piece of some problem.  Thus OpenMP has [worksharing constructs](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#WorkSharing), including "omp for".  In the case of an [OpenMP for](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#DO), the loop iterations are split up between threads, so that exactly one thread gets each iteration of the loop.  (For this to work, there are conditions on the loop itself.)  Clauses that set how that for loop is decomposed among threads - (schedule, collapse) go here, along with restrictions on how the iterations are executed (ordered), and some clauses about how variables are to be treated within the for loop as well.   Other examples of work sharing constructs in C are single - only one thread does the work - tasks, and sections.

So all threads execute the first printf statement, because all threads in the team hit it.  But the for loop iterations get split up between the threads, and each j only gets printed out by one thread.

If you don't need to have any code between when the parallel region starts and the for loop starts, one can combine the two directives as "omp parallel for", which both starts the parallel region and splits the (immediately) following for loop up between the threads.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the purpose of `omp parallel for` is not to make the code shorter but to avoid having to change the original code.  If there was only `omp parallel` and `omp for` the serial code compiled without `-fopenmp` would be different then it was before.

Comment: @Zboson, not if both directives are on two consecutive code lines with no other language constructs between them.

Comment: @HristoIliev, good point, so I'm wrong. Thank you for correcting me. I guess the purpose of `parallel for` is just to save one line of code then.

Comment: @HristoIliev, then one thing I said here [is-there-any-difference-between-variables-in-a-private-clause-and-variables-defi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890539/is-there-any-difference-between-variables-in-a-private-clause-and-variables-defi/23892073#23892073) is not entirely correctly. It could be done `#pragma parallel private(j)` new line then `#pragam omp for` which would not change the original code.

Comment: @Zboson, it is a shortcut notation, probably intended to save coding, especially in Fortran where it saves three lines of code. But there are some semantic differences between both as some worksharing constructs take clauses that are also valid in the `parallel` construct. Fortunately, the standard says: if program's behaviour would depend on whether a clause were applied to the parallel construct or to the worksharing construct, then it's UB.