# Computing entries of a matrix in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am very new to openMP, but am trying to write a simple program that generates the entries of matrix in parallel, namely for the N by M matrix A, let A(i,j) = i*j. A minimal example is included below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, 
         char **argv)
{
    int i, j, N, M;

    N = 20; 
    M = 20;

    int* A;
    A = (int*) calloc(N*M, sizeof(int));

    // compute entries of A in parallel 
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(A)
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < M; ++j){
            A[i*M + j] = i*j;
        }
    }

    // print parallel results
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < M; ++j){
            printf("%d ", A[i*M + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(A);

    return 0;
}
```

The results are not always correct. In theory, I am only parallelizing the outer loop, and each iteration of the for loop does not modify the entries that the other iterations will modify. But I am not sure how to translate this to openMP. When doing a similar procedure for a vector array (i.e. just one for loop), there seems to be no issue, e.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    v[i] = i*i;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how to fix this?

Comment: Does the problem only occur with paralleliing? Or does it also have wrong results in a simple program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to e.g. this
http://supercomputingblog.com/openmp/tutorial-parallel-for-loops-with-openmp/

The declaration of variables outside of a parallelized part is dangerous.
It can be defused by explicitly making the loop variable of the inner loop private.

For that, change this

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(A)
```

to

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j) shared(A)
```

Comment: That blog appears to be right. I was wondering how the nested loops were being synchronized, but had not got to the `private (j)` part yet. (I started with a long, long articles -- [Intro to OpenMP Mattson](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/Intro_To_OpenMP_Mattson.pdf) good historical article `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The issue in this case is that `j` is *shared* between threads which messes with the control flow of the inner loop. By default variables declared outside of a parallel region are *shared* whereas variables declared inside of a parallel region are *private*.

Follow the general rule to **declare variables as locally as possible**. In the for loop this means:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) {
```

This makes reasoning about your code much easier - and OpenMP code mostly correct by default. (Note `A` is shared by default because it is defined outside).

Alternatively you can manually specify `private(i,j) shared(A)` - this is more explicit and can help beginners. However it creates redundancy and can also be dangerous: `private` variables are uninitialized even if they had a valid value outside of the parallel region. Therefore I strongly recommend the implicit default approach unless necessary for advanced usage.